# How do I read an objects key in an indexeddb autoincrement objectstore, given an index

Tags: html, indexeddb

This question in code form, I can use `.put(doc, key)` to overwrite the object, but I cant figure out how to read its key

```
// After writing doc1 to an autoincrement
// objectStore, I want to overwrite it 
// later, I only know its index 
// (not its key)

var docs = [
  {'a':'doc1', 'my_index': 'anindex'},
  {'a':'doc2', 'my_index': 'anindex'}
];

indexedDB.deleteDatabase('foo').onsuccess = function () { 

  var idb;
  var req = indexedDB.open('foo');

  function writeDocs(docs) {

    if (!docs.length) { 
      console.log('done writing');
      return;
    }

    var txn = idb.transaction(['some_store_name'], 'readwrite');
    var doc = docs.shift();
    console.log('writing', doc);

    var get = txn.objectStore('some_store_name').index('my_index')
      .get(doc.my_index);

    get.onsuccess = function(e) { 

      var key = null;

      if (e.target.result) { 
        // If there is a result here, I want to overwrite it
        // to do that I need its key, cant find it here?    
        console.log(e.target.result);
      }

      var dataReq = txn.objectStore('some_store_name').put(doc);

      dataReq.onsuccess = function (e) {
        console.log('wroted', e.target.result);
        writeDocs(docs);
      }

      dataReq.onerror = function () { 
        console.log('it broke');
        writeDocs(txn, docs);
      }
    }
  };

  req.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
    var db = e.target.result;
    db.createObjectStore('some_store_name', {autoIncrement : true})
      .createIndex('my_index', 'my_index', {unique: true});
  };

  req.onsuccess = function(e) { 
    idb = e.target.result;
    writeDocs(docs);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  if (e.target.result) {
    // If there is a result here, I want to overwrite it
    // to do that I need its key, cant find it here?    
    console.log(e.target.result);
  }
```

`e.target.result` is in fact the key! But only as a response to `put` or `add`, not a `get`. You can use this value to `put()` the data in the future.

With out of line keys, like you have: `objectstore.put(data, key)`

With inline keys you can just `objectstore.put(data)`

**Update**: The problem is you're looping `writeDocs` but in your first loop `key` is `null` so it throws an error.

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/taylorbuley/Zh29z/).

**Second Update**: It looks like some code may have been added, or I missed something earlier. In addition to what I have flagged above, but your index is `unique` and you're using the same `my_index` value twice, hence the error on second `put()`. I avoided this problem in my fiddle solution by making `my_index` unique each pageload.

Comment: I dont have the context of the result of the .put, I only have the index, I figured out the answer though, inline keys will be places inside the document

Comment: Added a fiddle example to get you going.

Comment: key is always null, I never use it, was left over from another attempt, there hasnt been any edit to the question, I do think you misunderstand the question though, I have the index, I need the key

Comment: And for your example, yeh I cant store the key in this case, all I have is the index

Comment: You'll find the key at `e.target.result` in my example, as requested. A put always yields a key.

Comment: "I dont have the context of the result of the .put, I only have the index"

Answer (score 0):

Edited: The plain solution for this is to use `index.getKey(indexVal)`, switching to inline keys also worked, but would lead to a messy migration. changing `db.createObjectStore('some_store_name', {autoIncrement : true}).createIndex('my_index', 'my_index', {unique: true});` to `db.createObjectStore('some_store_name', {keyPath: 'seq', autoIncrement : true}).createIndex('my_index', 'my_index', {unique: true});`

```
// After writing doc1 to an autoincrement
// objectStore, I want to overwrite it 
// later, I only know its index 
// (not its key)

var docs = [
  {'a':'doc1', 'my_index': 'anindex'},
  {'a':'doc2', 'my_index': 'anindex'}
];

indexedDB.deleteDatabase('foo').onsuccess = function () { 

  var idb;
  var req = indexedDB.open('foo');

  function writeDocs(docs) {

    if (!docs.length) { 
      console.log('done writing');
      return;
    }

    var txn = idb.transaction(['some_store_name'], 'readwrite');
    var doc = docs.shift();

    var get = txn.objectStore('some_store_name').index('my_index')
      .get(doc.my_index);

    get.onsuccess = function(e) {

      if (e.target.result) { 
        doc.seq = e.target.result.seq;
      }
      var dataReq = txn.objectStore('some_store_name').put(doc);

      dataReq.onsuccess = function (e) {
        console.log('wroted', e.target.result);
        writeDocs(docs);
      }

      dataReq.onerror = function () { 
        console.log('it broke');
        writeDocs(txn, docs);
      }
    }
  };

  req.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
    var db = e.target.result;
    db.createObjectStore('some_store_name', {keyPath: 'seq', autoIncrement : true})
      .createIndex('my_index', 'my_index', {unique: true});
  };

  req.onsuccess = function(e) { 
    idb = e.target.result;
    writeDocs(docs);
  };
}
```

Comment: That's actually not the nut of your problems. See my updated answer.

Comment: For example, this code should still throw a uniqueness requirements error because `anindex` is used twice as a value for the unique index `my_index`

Comment: It wont / doesnt throw a constrainterror because I use the inline key to overwrite the existing entry - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zHhCx/. I would like to do it without specifying inline keys, but I cant find, given a single unique index, how to find the key of the object that refers to (also the title of the question)