# How to I upgrade an indexedDB objectStore to add a keyPath

Tags: html, indexeddb

I have an objectStore created with:

```
    db.createObjectStore('mystore', {autoIncrement: true})
      .createIndex('myindex', 'myindex', {unique: true});
```

I need to amend the schema to use inline keys, like:

```
    db.createObjectStore('mystore', {autoIncrement: true, keyPath: 'seq'})
      .createIndex('myindex', 'myindex', {unique: true});
```

I dont see any way to modify the object store like that inside a migration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the primary key for an object store cannot be changed after that object store's creation.

To migrate, you'll have to create a new store with your inline key and then copy over the data.

I'm guessing this is [related to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22563325/317937). Note that you don't need inline keys to use puts. The `IDBIndex` exposes a `put()` method as well. You can likely achieve what you're looking for by adding a new index and using it to `put()` your records.

Comment: Yup it is related, thanks a lot, will follow up in the other question, this one I needed to know and answered anyway, cheers